# Jupyter Notebook says that my disk quota is being exceeded, but I have plenty of space in my home directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run my Jupyter Notebook, but soon after running all the cells, I get the following error.

```
Unexpected error while saving file <notebook path> [Errno 122] disk quota exceeded
```

The thing is though, I have plenty of space available, so I don't know how I could have exceeded my disk space. I've looked elsewhere, and somebody said to delete the following file:

```
~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite
```

I did that, but I still encounter the same issue. Are there temp files somewhere that I need to delete?

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Lab, and their assorted kernels all operate the same way.  These notebooks open and function in whatever directory you choose to launch the notebooks from.

Some people use the command prompt and then navigate using the change directory command (cd) to move to their chosen folder.  Once at that chosen folder, then from the command prompt, type: Jupyter Notebook, or Jupyter Lab.  The Notebook then launches in that folder.

Other people, me included, use git bash to launch a Notebook.  Just use the windows explorer and click to whatever folder suites you fancy, then using the mouse context menu (right click in that folder) and select, Open in Bash.  Then in the Ming64 terminal, type, Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab.

New notebook files (name. ipynb) will be in whichever folder you've decided to launch the Notebook from.  The Notebooks will autosave. The autosave config can probably be adjusted, but I've never bothered.

Watch for the autosave across the bottom of the Notebook workspace.  It will usually indicate, "Saving Completed", otherwise is will indicate saving is occurring.