# Jupyter Notebook Won't Open Erno122

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, errno, quota

I'm trying to open Jupyter Notebook for some fairly heavy data analysis (pulling in datasets from hdf5 files and looking at certain aspects of them).  I've done this in the past, but recently had to log out and am now getting

```
IOError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: u'/nethome/myname/.local/share/jupyter/runtime-nbserver-14392.json
```

I've already seen that if I try to look at too much from any dataset at a time or too many datasets, it kills the kernel, but now I can't even open it.

I've looked at the info at https://superuser.com/questions/1427724/jupyter-oserror-errno-122-disk-quota-exceeded, but using the solution there `du --si -s $HOME` shows that I only have 1.1G there, well below my allowable quota.

I also looked at [Jupyter Notebook says that my disk quota is being exceeded, but I have plenty of space in my home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046299/jupyter-notebook-says-that-my-disk-quota-is-being-exceeded-but-i-have-plenty-of), but it frankly didn't seem as helpful.

I've checked my disk usage and it seems I have a fair amount of space left.

```
(base) [myname@mycomputer ~]$ df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            16G   61M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            16G  1.6G   15G  10% /run
tmpfs                            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/physvg01-slash       79G   21G   54G  28% /
/dev/sda2                       976M  344M  565M  38% /boot
/dev/sda1                       300M  9.9M  290M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/physvg01-var         20G   14G  4.9G  74% /var
/dev/mapper/physvg01-localdata  1.7T  1.4T  279G  84% /localdata
phys-file:/data/home/myname      12T  5.7T  5.6T  51% /nethome/myname
tmpfs                           3.2G   68K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1088055
```

Any help is appreciated as I need to do some analysis in there as soon as possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is obvious that your local machine has no more sufficient memories for this kernel. So my suggestion for you is to try some alternatives such as Google Colab, Kaggle Notebook, or GCP AI Platforms' notebook (not free if you have already signed up and run out of the free quota). I hope it works!

Comment: I haven't done much on this machine; and have used this notebook before without issue.    The kernel was killed, and now restarting it is proving impossible.  I'm wondering what/where I can clear space since it seems that I have plenty of memory according to every metric I can see.  Is there any possible way to clear up space or otherwise enable my machine to do calculations?

Comment: Sounds similar to one of my recent experiences. My notebook got stuck when the program printed out the many things on the output cell. My solution is simply uploading this notebook to Colab, and then canceled the output content and finally downloaded a new version. I'm afraid this won't always work, so perhaps you need to modify directly on the source file of the notebook, which could be opened with notepad.

Comment: Thanks; this seems to have worked.  Basically just copied the ipynb to Colab, cancelled everything, saved a new copy and downloaded it to work in Jupyter.  Wish I had a better understanding of what caused it, but that's on me to get better with all this stuff.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: I face this error on a setup where `$HOME` is limited in storage by default. I don't have the option to expand it. I do have another large volume empty. Is it possible to force jupyter to use that large volume instead?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issu. 
I noticed that every try, a new `runtime-nbserver-****.json` file is created.

I solved in by removing recent files by `rm /path/to/runtime-sbserver-files`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem with this error:

`Failed to start the Kernel. [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded. View Jupyter [log](command:jupyter.viewOutput) for further details.`

I solved it by doing the same as above, removing the files:

```
/home/..path../.local/share/jupyter/runtime/runtime-nbserver-***.son
```